# String literals from array of object

Tags: typescript

I have the next code:

```
interface IPeople {
 id: number,
 role: string
}

const peoples: IPeople[] = [
 {
  id: 1,
  role: 'student'
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  role: 'teacher'
 }
]
```

I need to get the type of string literals based on peoples roles:

```
type PeoplesRoles = 'student' | 'teacher'
```

Can i do it dinamically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `peoples` array immutable so TS is able to infer all keys and values.

```js
interface IPeople {
  id: number,
  role: string
}

const peoples = [
  {
    id: 1,
    role: 'student'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    role: 'teacher'
  }
] as const;

type Peoples = typeof peoples;

//  "student" | "teacher"
type PeoplesRole = Peoples[number]['role']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUIHsAOAbFAbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaMiqLAugZzBRQAczIBfMmQRYQg5Dmz4I-ZAF5kAbS7IS5CpVrIAjJ33deEOgHJBDKhHDWd4sxT0HDdAExuDPPmRrSEQAC2hnfUlSAF1kOFUZOTAAbilSMABPRWRMXAJVDSzFLBgFJQK00jIAehqKACI7B3AG5AAfZAaQhHCoBrJilDzlfgAlS3VcipVNRlZoGM1rAIhrGKA)

**UPDATE**

> If `role` is optional ...

```js
interface IPeople {
  id: number,
  role: string
}

const peoples = [
  {
    id: 1,
    role: 'student'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  }
] as const;

type Peoples = typeof peoples;

type ObtainRole<T> =
  (T extends any
    ? (T extends { role: infer Role }
      ? Role
      : never
    )
    : never
  )
  
// "student"
type PeoplesRole = ObtainRole<Peoples[number]>
```

Why i have used `T extends any` ? - To distribute the union type. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

After union distribution, this line `T extends { role: infer Role }` applies to every element.

Comment: thanks, its work fine, but is possible to little change code. If role a optional parameter and one of object dont have it ```{id: 1,role: 'student'},{id: 2}``` ? Then get just "student". Thanks

Comment: @kofyohugna made an update